# Open and close txt files with emacs in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, emacs

I wrote a script which opens several text files that I need during my work (e.g. journals etc.). The script looks like:

```
#! /bin/bash

DOCPATH=$HOME/Documents
NUMDOCPATH=$DOCPATH/Numerics

emacs $DOCPATH/UTA_WorkProtocol.txt &

emacs $NUMDOCPATH/NumProtocol.txt &

emacs $NUMDOCPATH/CITCOM/Protocol.txt &
```

That works fine and the files are opend properly. However, at the end I would like to create another script to save and close those files again. But, I haven't been able to find any commands to save and/or close open emacs files running in the background using a bash script. I would be more convenient to just run such a script instead of doing C-X C-s in each txt file as I might be adding new files to the "opening"script as well.

Could any more experienced person help me with that, please. Thanks!

Comment: Why? What are you doing with an emacs window running in the background?

Comment: I basically using protocol files to write down things I have done and found out. Therefore, I start the files in the beginning, write everything down that's important and would like to close all of them automatically when I am done with only one command.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit of a hack, but `bash` scripts aren't really suited to this type of UI scripting.

```
#! /bin/bash

DOCPATH=$HOME/Documents
NUMDOCPATH=$DOCPATH/Numerics

emacs $DOCPATH/UTA_WorkProtocol.txt &
emacs $NUMDOCPATH/NumProtocol.txt &
emacs $NUMDOCPATH/CITCOM/Protocol.txt &

emacs   # *Not* in the background
kill $(jobs -p)
```

When you are ready to close all the backgrounded instances of emacs, just close the one that is in the foreground. This will cause the final `emacs` to exit, which will allow the script to continue to the `kill` command, which will kill the remaining background jobs.

Note that the final `emacs` could be any command that blocks the script from completing and can be easily killed itself.

Comment: Well, this seems to be ok. However, if I don't have saved any of the open ones, all changes made are lost.

Comment: Someone who actually knows `emacs` (not me) should post an answer which explains how to replace the `kill` command that sends the appropriate command to each running instance of `emacs` to save and shutdown properly.

Answer (score 2):

Must you use bash ? It's easy in Emacs lisp :

```
(defun open-files ()
  (interactive)
  (find-file "UTA_WorkProtocol.txt")
  (find-file "NumProtocol.txt")
  (find-file "CITCOM/Protocol.txt"))

(defun close-files ()
  (interactive)
  (save-buffers-kill-emacs)
```

Then open a single instance of Emacs and run those commands in `M-x`.